# How "long gone" can be used in a sentence

Tags: adjective-phrases, subject-complement

"Long gone" is a phrase which means "gone a long time ago; used up a long time ago" according to [this link](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/long+gone).

The following sentences are some samples of its usage:

- The ice cream and cake are **long gone**. You are simply too late for the refreshments.
- **Long gone** are the days when program verification was a task carried out
  merely by hand with paper and pen.
- We are back at work, the weather is dull and the festive season is **long gone**.

What grammatical role "long gone" took in above sentences? Is it noun or adjective or neither!? What other roles it can take in a sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What grammatical role "long gone" took in above sentences?

I'm not sure but my guess is that **long** is an adverb. It modifies the adjective **gone**. Together, these two words form an idiom (an *[adjective phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase)*) with the approximate adjectival meaning "that which has passed a long time ago; gone a long time ago".

In the sentence

> The ice cream and cake are **long gone**.

The **long gone** part is a "*[subject complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement)*", just as **red**  in

> The ball is **red**.

The same applies to your two other example sentences. A subject complement is used to either describe the subject ("the ice-cream and cake") or to rename it. In your sentences, it is clear that the idiom **long gone** describes the subjects: it could be called a "[predicative adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression)". So it's an "adjective", not a "noun" after all.

Your second example sentence might baffle a beginner. It has a changed word order. We can remodel it to the standard order (subject - verb - object):

> The days when program verification was a task carried out merely by hand with paper and pen are **long gone**. (the subject - the copular verb "are" - the predicative adjective "long gone")

The idiom can also be used as an [attributive adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective#Types_of_use), serving as an attribute and standing *before* a noun, not after the copula:

> "Pops, did you hear the story of long John Dean?"
>   "Not yet, drummer!"
>   A bold bank robber from Bowlin' Green
>   Was sent to the jailhouse yesterday
>   But late last night he made his getaway
>
> He was long gone from Kentucky
>   Long gone, ain't he lucky?
>   Long gone, what I mean
>   [A **long gone** John from Bowlin' Green](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kV_5ewikm0) (<-- *[attributive adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase)* use of **long gone**; we have the proper noun "John" with the attribute "long gone")

What kind of a John he is? A **long-gone** John. (we sometimes [use the hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound#Hyphenated_compound_modifiers) to make the adjective phrase more readable, turning it into a *compound*).

It can also be used as a [post-positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-positive_adjective) adjective phrase:

> In times **long gone**, the harvest was a prolonged effort by hand and horse. (*Moods of the Ohio Moons: An Outdoorsman's Almanac*, 1991)

Here, the adjective phrase **long gone** modifies the noun **times**.

---

You mention a possible noun use. In some expressions with subject complements the predicative expression (the part after the [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)#English)) indeed serves a noun role and is called a "*[predicative nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression)*":

> The ice-cream and cake are **delicacies**. (**are** is the copular verb, after it comes the predicative nominal that serves as a "noun" renaming the "ice-cream and cake")

Can **long gone** be used as a noun ("predicative nominal") in a sentence "X is long gone"? No, unless you intend to baffle the reader, to engage in a word play.

It is sometimes reframed as a noun in other kinds of sentences:

> So we've opted out of the system and have decided to let happy **long gones** be cherished bygones and leave it at that. (Google Books)

Here, we see that **long gones** are some things that are long gone.

Answer (score 0):

It's an idiom. Idioms are generally free from their *grammatical role* but they have a great semantic impact.

I'm not sure what to call an idiom! Idiom is just an idiom and they don't ***typically*** work like adjectives or nouns. We learn the way they are.

If you see this particular idiom, it might work as an adjective as well - *a long-gone friend*. In other examples, it might work as *adverb*. But it's never sure.

As far as the sentences are concerned and your title goes, they can be used to mean [*gone a long time ago*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/long+gone). But structure wise, *long* is modifying the *gone*.